# What is Facebook callback_url and how to use it in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am using the `Facebook Graph API` in my rails projects, no matter I use `oauth2` gem or `koala`, It need `callback_url`

**Oauth2**

`token = client.auth_code.get_token('code_value', :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/callback')`

**Koala**

`@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(app_id, app_secret, callback_url)`

I try to use `http://localhost:3000/callback` in my project, but it's not working.

Should I develop a routes for that?

like: `get 'callback' => 'oauth#callback'`?

What should I write in the `callback` method in `OauthController`, what does it use for? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should.
Basically, OAuth uses callback data to provide tokens for authenticating users.

For example

- user clicks on "sign in" (or whatever) link and your app redirects they to the OAuth provider (or open it in the iframe).
- user permits to your app to use they profile details
- OAuth provider send callback to your app with unique code
- app uses that code to get secure access token for API communications

That's just a basic example.

In your case you need to implement controller that will parse callback data.

Here is the code example

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(api_key, app_secret, callback_url)
=> #<Koala::Facebook::OAuth:0x007fc919d014e0 @app_id=1234567890, @app_secret="FaKeAppSecretKey", @oauth_callback_url="http://localhost:3000/callback">

@oauth.url_for_oauth_code
=> "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=893637180663238&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcallback"
```

And when you go to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=893637180663238&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcallback` FB will redirect you to

```
http://localhost:3000/callback?code=CODE_FROM_CALLBACK
```

Then you should use implement controller that uses code to get access token

```
access_token = @oauth.get_access_token(params[:code])
=> "ACCESS_TOKEN"

@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
 => #<Koala::Facebook::API:0x007fc91a903ae0  @access_token="ACCESS_TOKEN", @app_secret=nil>

profile = @graph.get_object("me")
=> {"id"=>"4492344324865", "email"=>"my_fake_email_address@gmail.com", "first_name"=>"Roman", "gender"=>"male", "last_name"=>"Sotnikov", "link"=>"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/4492344324865/", "locale"=>"en_US", "name"=>"Roman Sotnikov", "timezone"=>6, "updated_time"=>"2015-05-18T05:19:54+0000", "verified"=>true}
```

Please check https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth for additional info.

Comment: @Stephen, please mark my answer as right if it was useful. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you explain the logic, for example, how to get Facebook username to display in the `index.html` page. thanks

Comment: Sure, I created a gist with example https://gist.github.com/retgoat/93a83f3ed620b9f99242cb34c70165e2

Comment: Thanks for your example, actually my question focus on how to get the `codes and auth_tokens`. Currently I understand that the `url_for_oauth_code` need to be click and open on browser by user. I am working on the `api` project, so that's why I don't understand this step, because no view exist. Haha, I know the basic rails implement you wrote for the `controller` and `view` stuff.

Comment: Ah, sorry for that :) Just misunderstood your comment. Actually, you should redirect users even if you have an API project.
In that case you should return a redirect url and a fron end part should change window.location to it.

Please have a look on gist I provided before. I updated it.

Comment: Please note that just an exampe and it completely untested.

Answer (score 1):

Callback Url is yours applications url -- a GET route --  you want the third party application to redirect to, after its done its work.

So in your routes.rb file simply create a get route

```
get 'facebook_graph_callback', to: 'controller_name#action'
#A get route which is connected to a controller action
```

Usually the third party will give you some sort of information back. Quite often its some sort of code. In your controller action you can use find them in `params` hash.